# React Routing 404 error HEROKU

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, react-router, react-router-dom

При открытии приложения все ок, далее перехожу на любую страницу и сначала (на секунду) все рендерится, потом все падает с ошибкой. Локально все работает. Для сервера я использую json-server

> GET https://clothes-shop-copy.herokuapp.com/catalog/womancollection/obuv/113458 404 (Not Found)

```
 server.js

import pkg from 'json-server';
import path from 'path'; 
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import express from 'express';


const { create,  router: _router,  defaults , rewriter } = pkg;
const dirname = path.dirname;
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const server = create();
const router = _router('users.json');
const middlewares = defaults({
  static: './build'
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
server.use(middlewares);
server.use(rewriter({
  '/api/*': '/$1',
}))
server.use(router);

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

server.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build' , 'index.html'));
});
console.log(__dirname);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server is running');
});
```

Также у меня есть файл static.json

```
{
"root": "build/",
"clean_urls": false,
"routes": {
  "/**": "index.html"
}
```

}

Прикладываю HEROKU LOGS

```
2022-05-13T14:51:20.903568+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /users/164f6f53-d2db-4708-91b7-9505b580c3a2 [36m304[0m 2.971 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:51:21.043508+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /womancollection [32m200[0m 3.729 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:51:23.183831+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /womancollection [36m304[0m 4.233 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:51:23.194414+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /users/164f6f53-d2db-4708-91b7-9505b580c3a2 [36m304[0m 2.939 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:51:23.811276+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /womancollection [32m200[0m 4.597 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:51:23.812136+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /users/164f6f53-d2db-4708-91b7-9505b580c3a2 [32m200[0m 4.760 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:51:23.954422+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /users/164f6f53-d2db-4708-91b7-9505b580c3a2 [36m304[0m 2.932 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:53:50.583997+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /users/164f6f53-d2db-4708-91b7-9505b580c3a2 [36m304[0m 2.330 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:53:50.586460+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /womancollection [36m304[0m 4.184 ms - -[0m
2022-05-13T14:53:52.637884+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /users/164f6f53-d2db-4708-91b7-9505b580c3a2 [36m304[0m 2.797 ms - -[0m
```

Comment: проблемы с путями наверное

Answer (score 0):

Спустя три дня и перепробовав все возможные варианты , проблему удалось решить, ****сменив  BrowserRouter  на HashRouter при построении путей.**** Надеюсь этот ответ будет полезен всем, кто столкнется с этой проблемой.